# How to set plaid background image regularly?

Tags: android

I'm just starting android programming and so I'm really noob!
I'm trying to set a plaid image as a background and I want to prevent from shuffling the squares in background and becoming rectangle when phone rotates!
can you come up with a solution to my problem!? preferably handling in XML file! tnx

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I had just disabled rotation in those activity!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are asking for:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/background_image"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/text" />
                 </FrameLayout>
    <!-- rest of your layout !-->

    </RelativeLayout>
```

just make sure that your image for background is big enough to fill big screen sizes.

Comment: Best and easiest way. Exactly like set background position fill mode in windows! Thanks for the answer!